# Garbage Collector seems to cause the Button in my MahApps.Metro Custom Dialog to stop working

Tags: data-binding, garbage-collection, structuremap, mahapps.metro, customdialog

I am trying to write a simple custom dialog with one button to close/hide it. The code is mostly taken from the from the MahApps Examples Application with slight modifications. I am using a dialog service (called `AutomationDialogService`) to open the dialog from my ViewModel (see code below).

The problem I having, is that I am seeing weird behavior from my custom dialog. When I start my program, my button works correctly and executes the action to close the dialog as expected (see code). This works two to three times, if do it in quick succession, until it stops working. At that point, the dialog opens, but the button does not work any more. The point in time at which the button stops working seems to coincide with a run of the Garbage Collector (GC) as indicated in the Diagnostics Tools of Visual Studio.

Unfortunately I don't even know were to start looking/debugging. What I don't understand, is that my code is very similar to the code used in the .Net 4.5 `CustomDialogExampleContent.cs`, which pops up when you select "Show CustomDialog via VM" from the Dialogs drop-down menu of the example application include MahApps.Metro. But my code it does not work.

Therefore, the problem may be related to my usage of Dependency-Injection with StructureMap 4.3. Since this is a Plugin, I have put its registry into a separate file `PluginRegistry`. I also added the relevant entries as code snippets below. I should add, that I am using the same registry entries for my main `DialogService`, without any issues.

I would be grateful, if anyone could provide any pointer, as to what I could try to debug this strange issue.

After much talking, here is the code I have:

Dialog-related code in `AutomationDialogService`:

```
private CustomDialog automationRunningDialog;
private AutomationRunningDialogViewModel customDialogContent;
public async void OpenAutomationRunningDialog()
{
        automationRunningDialog = new CustomDialog() { Title = "Automation Running" };

        customDialogContent = new AutomationRunningDialogViewModel(instance =>
        {
            dialogCoordinator.HideMetroDialogAsync(parentViewModel, automationRunningDialog);
        });

        automationRunningDialog.Content = new AutomationRunningDialogView { DataContext = customDialogContent };

        await dialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync(parentViewModel, automationRunningDialog);
}
```

ViewModel of the `AutomationDialog`:

```
class AutomationRunningDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AutomationRunningDialogViewModel(Action<AutomationRunningDialogViewModel> closeButtonHandler)
    {
        buttonCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            closeButtonHandler(this);
        });
    }

    private ICommand buttonCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonCommand => buttonCommand;
}
```

And this is the corresponding `AutomationRunningDialogView`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Extensions.Automation.Dialogs.AutomationRunningDialogView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Extensions.Automation.Dialogs"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="0 8 0 8"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}">
            OK
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code snipptes from `PluginRegistry` related to `AutomationDialogService`:

```
this.ForConcreteType<AutomationDialogService>()
    .Configure
    .Ctor<IDialogCoordinator>("dialogCoordinator").Is(c => c.GetInstance<DialogCoordinator>())
    .Ctor<ViewModelBase>("parentViewModel").Is(c => c.GetInstance<MainWindowDialogParentViewModel>())
    .Singleton();
this.For<IAutomationDialogService>()
    .Use(c => c.GetInstance<AutomationDialogService>())
    .Singleton();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RelayCommand action is accessing a closure (closeButtonHandler), which is being garbage collected:

```
buttonCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    closeButtonHandler(this);
});
```

and therefore you need to use the keepTargetAlive parameter of RelayCommand:

```
buttonCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    closeButtonHandler(this);
}, keepTargetAlive: true);
```

Further details here http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/weakaction.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

I thought my code was sufficiently similar to the MahApps-Example, but it was not. The MahApps example uses its own command `SimpleCommand`, while my code used the `RelayCommand` from `MvvmLight`.

I can eliminate the problem by replacing the following lines in `AutomationRunningDialogViewModel`:

```
buttonCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    closeButtonHandler(this);
});
```

with these:

```
buttonCommand = new SimpleCommand
{
    ExecuteDelegate = o => closeButtonHandler(this)
};
```

The main difference seems to be the signature of the command delegate-action between these two commands. For `ExecuteDelegate` in `SimpleCommand` it is:

```
public Action<object> ExecuteDelegate { get; set; }
```

where as for the ctor of `RelayCommand` it is:

```
public RelayCommand(Action execute);
```

So there is an obvious difference. But I don't understand, why this causes the problematic behavior with `RelayCommand` mentioned above, and if there is some way to continue using `RelayCommand` instead of `SimpleCommand`.

I would be grateful for comments!

Comment: Hello, did you find how to make it work with RelayCommand? I'm having the same problem..